# Who take care of file close/file locks if exception handling terminates in between?

Tags: c++, exception

So, consider this code which has RAII concept embedded. Since we are throwing an int and catching an float, program would go into terminate mode and abort. In such cases, who is responsible for file closing and removing file locks?

```
#include<cstdio>
class MyFile {
  FILE* fp;
  public:
  MyFile(const char* fp);
  ~MyFile();
};

MyFile::MyFile(const char* f) {
  std::cout << "Opening the file" << std::endl;
  fp = fopen(f, "w+");
}

MyFile::~MyFile() {
  std::cout << "Closing the file" << std::endl;
  fclose(fp);
}

int main() {
  MyFile f("foo.c");
  try {
    int a = 5;
    throw a;
  } catch(float a) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Nobody is responsible. The entire process gets nuked from high orbit.

Comment: The OS is responsible, when a program terminates the OS will free any claimed resources.

Comment: "program would go into terminate mode and abort. In such cases, who is responsible for file closing and removing file locks?" - Your operating system, when the program terminates.

Comment: _"...RAII concept embedded..."_ use RAII for your file handles.  Either use C++ file objects (eg `std::ifstream`) or `std::unique_ptr` with custom closer (deleter).

Comment: @RichardCritten ? What do you mean? Thanks for coming by.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I see. That's what I thought. Cheers!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "Nobody is responsible" - Not quite true. The OS is responsible and will clean up.

Comment: @HemantBhargava you are using `C` file objects have add a bit to my above comment.

Comment: "`FILE* fp;`" - in C++? Why?

Comment: @RichardCritten, This is also RAII. Right? I mean I can make it more funky by using smart/unique pointers, but it conveys what it had to. Isn't it?

Comment: @JesperJuhl :) Good point. Should take care of that and use streams.